# Perl script search/replace and transform results

Tags: regex, perl

I am running a simple Perl script which duplicates all lines starting with `\txt` to `\xtx`. So far so good.

```
use strict;
use warnings;    

$^I = '.bak';

while ( <> ) {

   s/(\\txt )(.*)/$1$2\n\\xtx $2/g;

   print; 
}
```

Now I would like to "scrub" all the new lines starting with `\\xtx` and

1. Delete all non-word characters: any character that is non-alphabetic but keeping characters with diacritics
2. Convert everything to lower case.

And that's where my rudimentary programming skills end

My text file looks like this:

```
\txt Text (.) with [ symbols and Num[bers (.2) and cháractẽrs with diacrítics  
\abc More text ...
```

My script so far produces:

```
\txt Text (.) with [ symbols and Num[bers (.2) and cháractẽrs with diacrítics  
\xtx Text (.) with [ symbols and Num[bers (.2) and cháractẽrs with diacrítics  
\abc More text ...
```

And I would like to achieve:

```
\txt Text (.) with [ symbols and Num[bers (.2) and cháractẽrs with diacrítics  
\xtx text with symbols and numbers and cháractẽrs with diacrítics  
\abc More text ...
```

Any help much appreciated!

*EDIT:*
Here's a real example string:

```
\_sh v3.0  400  Text3  

\ref 2013-05-01_08.36.14 001  
\txt Djawy (.) de osẽ[ma (.2) EDJu::  
\fts Te equivocaste, saliste,   
\fte   

\ELANParticipant #TBGD  
\ELANBegin 00:00:05.367  
\ELANEnd 00:00:06.521  
\dt 26/May/2016  

\ref 2013-05-01_08.36.14 002  
\txt [A;;;;;;;;;;;;;   
\fts A;;;;;;;;;;;;;  
\fte   
...
```

... everything should stay as is, except for the lines starting with \txt ...

Comment: `duplicates all lines starting with \txt` = `s/^(\\txt )(.*)/$1$2\n\\xtx $2/mg`

Comment: You'd need the `s///eg` eval form to do this. And preserve/shrinking formatting via spaces will be a little tedious, but doable.

Comment: Could you provide real example string, because I don't think your description is very clear.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I just edited the question with some real data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this conversion

Perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

binmode (DATA, ":utf8");
binmode (STDOUT, ":utf8");

while (<DATA>) {
   s/^(\\txt )(.*)/GetConvetedLine($1,$2)/me;
   print; 
}

sub GetConvetedLine
{
    my ($txt, $body) = @_;
    my $newbody = $body;
    $newbody =~ s/[^\pL\s]+//g;
    $newbody =~ s/\s+/ /g;
    $newbody = lc($newbody);
    return $txt . $body . "\n" . "\\xtx " . $newbody;
}


__DATA__    
\txt Text (.) with [ symbols and Num[bers (.2) and cháractẽrs with diacrítics
```

Output

```
\txt Text (.) with [ symbols and Num[bers (.2) and cháractẽrs with diacrítics
\xtx text with symbols and numbers and cháractẽrs with diacrítics
```

Comment: Thank you!, this looks like it's going to do it!   Would you mind explaining how I can get that to `print` the output to the original file (as in the original example?) So that I can say `perl script.pl myfile.txt`   Sorry, if this should be obvious, but I'm a total beginner at perl :/

Comment: "... he who seeks shall find ..." – I think I figured it out ... I put the code that I've ended up using below, when you get a chance would you mind checking real quick if I made any big mistakes?  (it does produce the correct output so I guess everything's fine)   Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor it a bit, so you don't have to put it all into one regex:

```
use strict;
use warnings;    
$^I = '.bak';
while (<>) {
    print; 
    if(/^\\txt/) {
        s/^\\txt//; # remove \txt
        s/[\[\]\(\)//g; # remove all unwanted characters
        print "\xtx $_";
    }
    print; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this!  But this script duplicates all other lines too.  And I also couldn't get it to remove the symbol characters.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, this is the (slightly modified) version of sln's answer above that I ended up using.  It can be invoked the same way that I used to invoke the original script with `perl script.pl myfile.txt`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
$^I = '.bak'; # create a backup copy 

while (<>) {
   s/^(\\txt )(.*)/GetConvetedLine($1,$2)/me;
   print;
}

sub GetConvetedLine
{
    my ($txt, $body) = @_;
    my $newbody = $body;
    $newbody =~ s/[^\pL\s]+//g;
    $newbody =~ s/ \s+/ /g;
    $newbody = lc($newbody);
    return $txt . $body . "\n" . "\\xtx " . $newbody;
}
```

Comment: Yea, it looks ok. You don't need the print in GetConvertedLine(), and I would use `$newbody =~ s/\s+/ /g;` like the original. `\R` means linebreak. Basically, there are never any linebreaks in $newbody, since that is the match from `(.*)` meaning match anything _except_ linebreaks.

Comment: Thank you @sln. I had put the \R because for some reason I would get some weird "Windows" line break characters at the end of the `$newbody` (probably due to some carriage returns from the original file) and then the next line (depending on the text editor) wasn't on the next line anymore.  \R seemed to get rid of them.  But I now found a better solution which is searching for `s/ \s+/ /g;` (i.e., a space before `\s+`). That would get rid of the problem.